# Is there a way to execute the second-to-last command that started with a given string?

Tags: bash, command-line

In a project with different makefiles:

```
$ make -f foo1.make
... ...
$ testing testing
... ...
$ !ma
make -f foo1.make
```

Good! But then if I by accident do:

```
$ make -f foo1.make
... ...
$ testing testing
... ...
$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

And now I am sad:

```
$ !!ma
makema
No command 'makema' found, did you mean:
  ... ...
```

Now I have to pick through all my testing commands with the up arrow like an animal. Unacceptable*!

Is there any way to re-run that full `make -f foo1.make` command using `!` or some variant thereof?

*: I will not even dignify the suggestion that I just retype the entire command with a response!

Comment: You could also use Ctrl-r to search backwards in history

Comment: To flesh out daniel's comment: hit Ctrl-R, type "ma", hit Ctrl-R until you've found the one you want, then hit Enter. This is "reverse incremental search". If you want "non-reverse", use Ctrl-S